# Disable or Unregistered Meteor.Accounts default login handler (loginWithPassword)

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have created my own custom login handler to authenticate users.

```
loginWithPasswordPlatfrom(user,passwd,platformId)
```

I want to disable the default login method `loginWithPassword(user,password)` of the meteor and force clients (android, ios, web)  to use my custom method.

but what happened if client call login with user and password parameter it is successfully logedin because default login is still registered in a meteor.

please suggest how to disable or unregister a login handler in meteor accounts.

Comment: did you figure it out? Got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify `Accounts._loginHandlers` on the server and throw out the default login method. `Accounts.loginWithPassword()` is then no longer possible on the client.

```
var hs = []
for(var i = 0; i < Accounts._loginHandlers.length; i++) {
    if(Accounts._loginHandlers[i].name != 'password') hs.push(Accounts._loginHandlers[i])
}
Accounts._loginHandlers = hs
```